# Android MediaPlayer- play two videos simultaneously with sync

Tags: android, performance, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer

My problem is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38602241/my-android-mediaplayer-synchronization-problems), but there was no correct answer, so I thought I give it a go.

In my application I've got two video players (`TextureView` + `MediaPlayer`- based on `VideoView`) playing from URL side by side on one screen. I got it working quite right. As I need then them to play simultaneously I synced their controllers, to when I start one of them the second starts too (the same with pausing, seeking, buffering, etc).

```
videoView1.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
            firstVideoPrepared = true;
            tryStart();
        }
    });

videoView2.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            secondVideoPrepared = true;
            tryStart();
        }
    });

private void tryStart() {
    // here is also buffered data level check
    if (firstVideoPrepared && secondVideoPrepared) {
        videoView1.start();
        videoView2.start();
    }
}
```

The problem is that despite pausing both videos for buffering, when I `start()` them they sometimes get out of sync. Let's say that there is the same video in both players- I need them to be sync almost ideally as I can see any difference. **Is there any way to keep them synced so precisely?**

I've read about libraries like [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), [FFMPEGMediaPlayer](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaPlayer) or [MediaPalyer-Extended](https://github.com/protyposis/MediaPlayer-Extended) but none of them seems to have what I need.

Is it even possible to keep that accuracy of videos sync?

Comment: Have you considered something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293265/ffmpeg-2-videos-transcoded-and-side-by-side-in-1-frame ?

Comment: The problem is that I have to keep videos in separate containers as one of the functionalities is hiding/showing one of the videos.
But this link addresses my question to some point. Unfortunately I'm not familiar with ffmpeg nor android ndk. Do you know of any wrappers I could use in Java code?

Comment: What's more, I've found some android-ffmpeg libraries but all of them are under GPL/LGPL licences and my project is commercial, so I can't really use it.